# Doing a segue from another controller

Tags: objective-c, delegates, tableview, uistoryboard, segue

This is my situation. I've two table views. After searching on working with two tableviews in one view, i came to the solution to make 2 extra controllers. Namely tbl1DatasourceDelegate and tbl2DatasourceDelegate.  Now when I push on a cell, it should segue to another viewController. I have this code in my tbl1DatasourceDelegate.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PlayerNews *news = [_tableSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PlayerDetailController *detail =[[PlayerDetailController alloc]init];

    [detail setNewsItem:news];
}
```

So when I select a Cell I make a playerNewsObject and send it back to my Controller with the 2 tableviews in it. When I got back in my controller with the two tableviews in it. (controller where I segue-ing from) I execute the function *setNewsItem* Here you see the code.

```
 -(void)setNewsItem:(PlayerNews *)newsItem{
        if(![_newsItem isEqual:newsItem]){
            _newsItem = newsItem;
        }
       NSLog(@"Player detail controller newsItem object: %@", _newsItem);
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PlayerDetailNews" sender:tblNews];

    }
```

This code is executed because my log shows the newsItem I pushed on the tableview. But It won't segue to it. I am using the following prepareForSegue.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"comes in this segue");
    // ask NSFRC for the NSMO at the row in question
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PlayerDetailNews"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_newsItem.image]];
        [segue.destinationViewController setNewsTitle:_newsItem.title];
        [segue.destinationViewController setNewsDescription:_newsItem.content];
        [segue.destinationViewController setNewsCopy:_newsItem.image_copyright];
        [segue.destinationViewController setNewsUrl:_newsItem.url];
        [segue.destinationViewController setNewsShortDescription:_newsItem.summary];
    }
}
```

It does not come in this method because it does not print the log. It crashes with the following error.

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<tblPlayerNewsDatasourceDelagete: 0x1e5e44c0>) has no segue with identifier 'showPlayerDetailNews''
```

Can anybody help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two reasons for not being able to launch a segue:

1) Misspelling of the segue identifier. Double check the identifier used in the Storyboard and your code. Side note: identifiers don't have to be unique in the storyboard, just for each viewcontroller. Let's say you have viewcontroller **A** with segue to **B** and a viewcontroller **C** with a segue to **B**, they are allowed to have the same identifiers.

2) Trying to launch a segue which is not connected to the UIViewController you're trying to launch it from. So for example: you have segue 'segueA' which connects viewcontroller **A** to **B**. In this case, the only place where you are able to use `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueA" sender:nil]` is **A**.